# How to break lines "inplace" with Atom Editor

Tags: python-3.x, ide, indentation, atom-editor, organization

When I'm typing a long line and press `Enter` in Atom Editor, I get the following:[image]

I would like to know to set it so when I press `Enter` (or something equivalent) I get something with the following flavor:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: FWIW, that doesn't look much better either.

Comment: It seems much clearer for my uses

Comment: On your example, you want `verbose` to align with `random_state`? Not with `n_estimators`?

Comment: Either way would be fine, @GinoMempin! I just don't want it starting in the right margin as in the picture!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install an indentation package for Atom.

Try the [**python-indent**](https://atom.io/packages/python-indent) package.
It automatically applies the [**PEP8 style guide for indentation**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) when you enter a newline.

[image: sample screenshot]

It also works when splitting method calls with many args same as your example.

Just make sure to configure the pre-included **language-python** package first to use "soft" tabs.
(Settings > Packages > language-python)

[image: soft tabs]